# KeyError on importing from a irrelevant function in the same file

Tags: python, import, keyerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergioleylanguren/Desktop/Route Decider/routelookup/app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from config import init_config
  File "/Users/sergioleylanguren/Desktop/Route Decider/routelookup/config.py", line 27, in <module>
    class Config:
  File "/Users/sergioleylanguren/Desktop/Route Decider/routelookup/config.py", line 32, in Config
    SECRET_KEY = values['SECRET_KEY']
                 ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

I'm unsure of what is going on here except that I think this may possible have to do with how python compiles code. The `KeyError` is being raised from the `Config` class which has not been called or initialized for that matter. My intentions with `init_config` is to run it before so if the .env file that the config is using is created with the values setup, the `Config` class can be set into the flask's application config object afterwards.

Is there a way to remedy this while keeping `init_config` within config.py or a different solution?

> app.py, lines 7-18

```py
from config import init_config
import atexit

# FILE_DIR and test_config
FILE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "data" / "data.txt"
test_config = None

# application
#load_dotenv()
init_config()

app = Flask(__name__)
```

> config.py, `init_config`, lines 14-24

```py
def init_config():
    """initilize config file if it doesn't exist"""
    if not isfile(env_file_fp):
        env_file_fp.touch(mode=0o600, exist_ok=False)

        set_env_key("SECRET_KEY", "")
        set_env_key("FLIGHTRADAR_USERNAME", "")
        set_env_key("FLIGHTRADAR_PASSWORD", "")
        set_env_key("NAVIGRAPH_USERNAME", "")
        set_env_key("NAVIGRAPH_PASSWORD", "")
        set_env_key("FLIGHTRADAR_API", "")
```

> config.py, `Config`, lines 27-36

```py
class Config:
    values = dotenv_values(env_file_fp)
    
    DEBUG = True
    DEVELOPEMENT = True
    SECRET_KEY = values['SECRET_KEY']
    FLIGHTRADAR_USERNAME = values['FLIGHTRADAR_USERNAME']
    FLIGHTRADAR_PASSWORD = values['FLIGHTRADAR_PASSWORD']
    NAVIGRAPH_USERNAME = values['NAVIGRAPH_USERNAME']
    NAVIGRAPH_PASSWORD = values['NAVIGRAPH_PASSWORD']
```

**Note:** If the .env file already exists, then the code will run without errors

Comment: Python runs code when you import the file. The `Config` class is created when that happens including the initialization of the class variables. If these were instead instance variables then you could delay the instantiation.